# How to pass parameter in mdx query

Tags: mdx

How to pass parameter in MDX query.
Below is my mdx qyery----

```
SELECT 
    NON EMPTY FILTER({ ( [Tbl Electricity].[Transaction Id].[Transaction Id] ) },  [Measures].[From Year]=2011 and [Measures].[To Month]=[Measures].[To Month].&['+@month+' ]) ON ROWS,
    NON EMPTY { [Measures].[From Year], [Measures].[To Year], [Measures].[To Month], [Measures].[From Month], [Measures].[Total Cost], [Measures].[Quantity] } ON COLUMNS
FROM [ECERM Dev1]
```

In above query, I am comparing `[From Year]` by 2011 and I would like to compare `[To Month]` dimension with my parameter `@month`.

By running above query I am getting below error

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the client or reporting tool you're using. XMLA protocol support [MDX parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187161.aspx) ( @month ).

However you need a client / library supporting this feature. What tool are you using ?